# Postgres query and Teampostgresql shows different value for shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am using postgresql 9.4.4 version on Ubuntu 12.04 with 8CPU and 16 GB RAM and in the postgresql.conf I have defined my shared)buffers=1GB. After restarting the server I see that the query `show shared_buffers;` gives me correct value which is 1GB. But when I use TeamPostgresql and select on the database I configured to connect, it shows numerous of the configurations and among them it shows shared_buffers = 131072 . No unit, assuming it is in kB, so it says shared_buffer is 128MB. I change the value to 512 MB in the conf file, query reflects the correct change, but in teampostgresql it shows 65536(64 MB?). Making it 128MB changes that value to 32768. I don't understand why it only shows 1/8th of the value I defined in the conf file. Anyone has come across this? Am I missing something here or is it a bug in the tool(or in the DB?) .

Any comment on this will be helpful.

Regards,
Subhankar

Comment: I believe it's a bug. they probably devide it by `block_size`. (I remember myself doing that on some settings either on Postgres or Oracle)

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks for commenting. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer. If I do a select * from pg_settings, for shared_buffers the value shown is 131072 and the unit shown is 8kB. So the unit is not kB but 8kB which is the page/block size I guess.

May be TeamPostgresql should show the unit as well in their front page so that people don't get confused. I hope this helps someone.